# Problem with calculating in Mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this book schema **(Mongoose Schema)**

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bookName: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 255,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },

    price: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: true
    },

    ratings: [Number],

    feedbacks: [String],
    
    author: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 255,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },

    info: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 1000,
        trim: true
    },

    avgRating: {
        required: true,
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        default: () => {
           let sum;
           for(i = 0; i < this.ratings.length; i++){ 
               sum+=this.ratings[i]; 
            }
           return sum/this.ratings.length;
        }
    }
});
```

It has an array of ratings as shown
the array has numbers in it
and has a field called avg rating
the average rating should equal the sum of the numbers in the array divided by the length of the array
I want to calculate the average rating in the database

I tried that code but it doesn't work

```
avgRating: {
    required: true,
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    default: () => {
       let sum;
       for(i = 0; i < this.ratings.length; i++){ 
           sum+=this.ratings[i]; 
        }
       return sum/this.ratings.length;
    }
}
```

could anyone help to calculate it in the database and to be updated also even if a new rating is being pushed to the array

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with mongoose and have a similar feature in one of my projects. Instead of defining it within your schema, have you considered patching the value when it changes?

Schema:

```
averageRating: {
   type: Number,
   default: 0
}
```

Review Router: averageRatings are updated in mongo when a new
review is posted to a particular foo.id; using mongoose's 'findByIdAndUpdate'.

```
const averageRatings = totalScore / count

foo.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.fooId, 
    { averageRating: averageRatings },
    { new: true }
)
.then(foo => res.json(foo))
})
```